# Android: Combine inputType:phone and inputType:numberPassword

Tags: android, xml, input, android-xml, android-keypad

I want to show the 'only digits' keyboard when user taps on the `editText`.
This can be achieved by

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

I also want my `editText` to hide the content. Which can be achieved by

`android:inputType="numberPassword"`

I tried to do both combined by doing:

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:password="true"
```

This worked but `android:password="true"` is deprecated. Is this possible to achieve in any other way?

Comment: Something is wrong and pipe (`|`) is ignored in this case (I just tried). So, looks like `android:inputType="numberPassword"` is the best shot you have got unless someone comes up with really cool solution.

Comment: You are right. The pipe should be working, but it isn't.

Comment: why don't you try to do this in code. I guess pipe would work there.

Comment: I was expecting that to work. Tried that just now. Unfortunately, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 android:inputType="number|numberPassword"
```

or you can also do this:

```
 android:inputType="phone|numberPassword"
```

Comment: That allows only numbers but that will open the regular keyboard. I want the 'only digits' keyboard to pop open.

Comment: I guess you mean `phone|numberPassword` but that isnt working. I already tried that.